# Xpath for data miner program

Tags: xml, parsing, xpath

I am sorry for my bad description. Let me clear my question. I want to parse data from a table in a webpage. So, I am currently using a google chrome apps named "data miner". I try to create the Xpath for the table (see the table illustration below). What I have done so far is like this :

1. For table 1, data 1 : `//div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr`
2. For table 2, data 1 : `//div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr`
3. For table 3, data 1 : `//div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr`

These 3 codes work for one table only if I concatenate it with `|`. The combined code is like this : 
`//div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr | //div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr | //div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr`

And the output order becomes : 
Table 1, Data 1 
Table 2, Data 1 
Table 3, Data 1

However, if I try to apply it for all data by changing the `div[1]` into `div`, the output order becomes : 
Table 1, Data 1 
Table 1, Data 2 
. 
. 
Table 1, Data 10 
Table 2, Data 1 
Table 2, Data 2 
. 
. 
Table 2, Data 10 
Table 3, Data 1 
Table 3, Data 2 
. 
. 
Table 3, Data 10

What I actually need is like this : 
Table 1, Data 1 
Table 2, Data 1 
Table 3, Data 1 
Table 1, Data 2 
Table 2, Data 2 
Table 3, Data 2 
. 
. 
Table 1, Data 10 
Table 2, Data 10 
Table 3, Data 10

Basically, `div[1]` represent data 1 and so on. `table[1]`, `table[2]`, and `table[3]` represent table 1, 2, and 3 in a specific data. Can someone give me suggestion how to combine these 3 codes so it will work fine for all the data? Or do you have any other solution?

The table illustration :
[Table model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1BGx.jpg)

Comment: Please show some of the XML you parse.

Comment: Also please use code-formatting on your expressions.

Comment: @FabianZeindl I am sorry for my bad format, I am still new in here and I am not really understand. I have created a better statement now.

Comment: No need for apologies, that's what review and moderation is for ;). Good that you've updated your question. Be sure to check the answer and, if any of them fits, use the checkmark to accept it.

Comment: I think I'm beginning to understand. Which version of XPath (1 or 2) are you using? Assuming it is XPath 1, then note that node sets are *unordered*, and the union of node sets is of course unordered, too. If I run a query similar to yours using `xmllint` on some sample XML data, I get the result in document order. But this is implementation defined. Maybe avoiding the union operator would help in your case, but I'm afraid I can't think of an XPath expression which will work in your case.

Comment: Yep, I am searching for another solution without using union operator. But, I can't find it yet. Hopefully, someone can give me another solution? I really want to understand a little bit !